# Chromium for android eclipse debugging / DDD for chromium C++ debugging

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, chromium

I'm developing simple project using Chromium for android is there some way to debug Chromium C++ code through eclipse debugger?

Right now i have possibility to debug C++ through Terminal using GDB or DDD.
In case how to use DDD here is short instruction:

1.Install ddd application

```
sudo apt-get install ddd
```

2.Change adb_gdb file in directory chromium/src/build/android

```
 change the line $GDB $GDBARGS -x $COMMANDS && to 
 ddd --debugger $GDB $GDBARGS -x $COMMANDS &&
```

1. cd /chromium/src
2. . build/android/envsetup.sh
3. build/android/adb_install_apk.py --apk ContentShell.apk
4. build/android/adb_run_content_shell
5. build/android/adb_gdb_content_shell
6. DDD application  (example, how to use)

   a. File->Open Source -> Filter  -> set filename  "ipc_chnnel_proxy.cc"  -> Open

   b. set breakpoints in the function  ChannelProxy::Context::OnMessageReceived

   c.  run the command Cont

   d. DDD will break on this breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxEclipseDev in particular the "Optional: Building inside Eclipse" section. It's still a bit flaky but works most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution to debug Chromium for Android from Eclipse. It involves the creation of some wrappers following the idea you propose in your step 2. Your proposal lacks a way of telling Eclipse to use that debugging scripts, but it can be done by properly tweaking the debug configuration in Eclipse to use the gdb/mi debugger and open the proper wrappers.

All the steps are explained in this post: http://blogs.igalia.com/eocanha/2014/10/14/hacking-on-chromium-for-android-from-eclipse-part-2